# is it possible to give default value to mat-select in html,not in ts in an angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angulat project in which I would like to give a default value to a dropdown in the HTML file and not in ts file. I want to give a default value in HTML and not in ts because of the constraints I have. I have a table in which I am dynamically adding dropdowns.

My HTML code.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th >
                            Select
                    </th>
                    <th>
                            Level
                    </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let level of LevelsConfigList">
                <td>
                        <mat-checkbox
                                (change)="level.ActiveFl = level.ActiveFl == 'Y' ? 'N':'Y'"
                                [checked] = "level.ActiveFl == 'Y'"
                                >             
                        </mat-checkbox>
                </td>
                <td>
                        {{level.EntityNm}}
                </td>
                <td >
                        <mat-form-field>
                                <mat-select placeholder="Type"
                                        [(ngModel)]="level.ConfigFl">
                                        <mat-option [value]="'Y'">Global
                                        </mat-option>
                                        <mat-option [value]="'N'">Local
                                        </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am not able to give a default value in ts file since I am dynamically adding rows. How to give default values to dropdown in such cases? I know a way to using native HTML in which we use selected element

```
<select name="plan" id="plan"> 
        <option value="free">Free</option> 
        <option value="starter" selected>Starter </option> 
        <option value="professional">Professional</option> 
        <option value="corporate">Corporate</option> 
    </select>
```

is something of this sort possible in angular ?

Comment: I think you can use **[selected]** input attribute to achieve your goal.

Comment: Did you try this on the mat select: [value]="level.ConfigFl || 'Y' " ?

Comment: @Muthupriya , I get an error `Can't bind to 'selected' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.'`

Comment: @AsafS. , tried , getting an error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '='`

Comment: my bad, it should be:  value="Y"

Comment: but then if your model - level.ConfigFl is null it will be overwritten from 1 to null, according to your model.